# Windows Live Mesh has been using full CPU for 4 days and has sawtooth memory usage

Tags: troubleshooting, windows-live-mesh

My Windows Live Mesh install has been using a full CPU core non-stop (including overnight) for more than 4 days now. I've rebooted the PC a couple of times during this time period, but the MOE.exe process keeps on doing this.

From past experience I know that Mesh has a tendency to do this whenever a significant number of changes are processed, but usually leaving it on overnight would fix this.

Also, the memory usage of WLSync.exe is a sawtooth shape, with a bunch of CPU/IO between the spikes:

[image]

This has also been going on for days and reoccurs after a reboot. The UI shows all files as up-to-date, and indeed they are. The exact same behaviour occurs on another PC that is part of this sync, so it doesn't look like a broken installation.

Any ideas for how to fix this?